# Can't make VM off Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-workstation

I've got a copy of WinXP off of MSDNAA, with a key. I've mounted it to my CD-drive, and now I'm trying to make it in to a VM.

The problem is, it seems that the thing is constantly trying to connect to a DHCP server, fails to connect and then decides no operating system was found.

The file I got off MSDNAA was an .img file, so I had to mount it to a virtual CD drive.

VmWare workstation comes with a Windows XP iso, tried that, also failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your written, it might be not a ISO file but a HDD image file. To make sure that using `file` to determine type. You can download it here, [Windows port](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).

Then, add it as a HDD image and start your VMWare Machine. I guess you will be guided through a sysprep setup.

Have fun,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like VMware isn't seeing the ISO of WinXP and is looking for DHCP to do a PXE boot.

I would change the extension of the IMG to ISO and tell VMware to use the ISO.

I believe the Windows XP ISO you found is for VMware to mount to install the guest OS tools.

Of course, you should also ensure the vm is set to have the CD-ROM connected at boot and the vm BIOS is configured to use the CD-ROM as a boot device.  Every now and then for some reason VMware will not connect my CD-ROM drive at boot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Making it in to an ISO did not work. I did alter the boot order in the BIOS and the CD is connected on startup.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the image is bootable or if the file is corrupt.  If it is an ISO format, the a tool like 7Zip will be able to open it and extract it into a directory like a zip file, and I guess that would mean it isn't bootable.  If 7Zip can't open it, then it could not an ISO format or corrupt.  I assume the site had a checksum (MD5 and SHA1) that you could check the integrity of the file.  I would double check it.  Also, in a few rare cases I've downloaded things that looked like a file type, but were actually a zip of the file.  After unzipping it, then I had my file.